# Simplify jQuery function

Tags: jquery

I have the following function:

```
var randomImages = ["bgr1","bgr2","bgr3","bgr4","bgr5","bgr6"];
var rndNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * randomImages.length);
$(".myDiv").css({ background: "url(/images/" + randomImages[rndNum] + ".gif)" });
```

Since all the images have the same name except the last numeric value, can't I simplify this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may seem obvious but if you know how many images you have you could replace randomImages.length with a constant e.g. 5 for arguments sake, then you dont need an array so it would be just one line:

```
$(".myDiv").css( { background: "url(/images/bgr" + Math.ceil(Math.random() * 5) + ".gif)" } );
```

Note: math.ceil would be better as then you dont need a +1.

Answer (score 3):

```
var numImages = 6;
var rndNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * numImages) + 1;
$(".myDiv").css({ background: "url(/images/bgr" + rndNum + ".gif)" });
```

Comment: Doesn't this require that the randomImages array remains defined? I got the feeling that the simplification the OP is seeking is to eliminate the need to define an array where the only difference in each value is the number at the end.

Comment: Doh, of course. Thanks. Stupid oversight... You don't need `randomImages.length`, you just need `6`. Editing...

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can. Note that you might want to define a constant rather than just using the magic number 6, but this is the idea.

```
var rndNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
$(".myDiv").css({ background: "url(/images/bgr" + rndNum + ".gif)" });
```